# If any column have value as F then main column set value as F

Tags: sql

There is 1 table as `job_detail` having columns & records are as below

```
Evnt_name   event_job_nm   status   start_time   end_time
---------   ------------   ------   ----------   ----------
evnt_abc    evnt_abc_job1   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_abc    evnt_abc_job2   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_abc    evnt_abc_job3   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_abc    evnt_abc_job4   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_jkl    evnt_jkl_job1   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_jkl    evnt_jkl_job2   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_jkl    evnt_jkl_job3   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_jkl    evnt_jkl_job4   F       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
.............
evnt_xyz    evnt_xyz_job1   C       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_xyz    evnt_xyz_job2   F       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_xyz    evnt_xyz_job3   N       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
evnt_xyz    evnt_xyz_job4   N       02/04/2023   02/04/2023
```

Status as C -> **Completed**, F -> **Failed**, N -> **Not started**
From above table, every event name have 4 job details. If every job of event name got succeeded then I want SQL query status of event name as completed/Success & if any of single job of event name got failed then status of event name as Failed only.

So from above case we need query where output like

```
Evnt_name    evnt_status
---------    -----------
evnt_abc       C
evnt_jkl       F
evnt_xyz       F
```

Could you please help me here to generate SQL query. Thanks

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please add your current SQL code and describe what is the issue with it. You need a conditional aggregation

Comment: SELECT Evnt_name, 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'F' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'F' 
        ELSE 'C' 
    END AS evnt_status 
FROM job_detail 
GROUP BY Evnt_name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT Evnt_name, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
            THEN 'C' 
            ELSE 'F' 
       END AS evnt_status
FROM job_detail
GROUP BY Evnt_name;
```

In the SELECT clause, use the `CASE` statement to check whether all jobs for an event have a status of C (Completed). If all jobs have a status of C, then the event status is C (Completed). Otherwise, the event status is F (Failed).

The `COUNT(*)` function counts the total number of jobs for each event, and the SUM() function with the CASE statement counts the number of jobs that have a status of C.

Comment: @Vojtech Thanks, i got the result set